# Есть ли альтернатива питоновского типа enumerate в php?

Tags: php, python

В PHP новичок от слова совсем, появилась задача написать генератор случайных чисел с идентификаторами, в питоне например про такой тип, как enumerate слышал,  правда не использовал никогда, но насколько понимаю что-то подобное упростило бы задачу.
Если есть какие-то решения по данной задаче, с радостью выслушаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А в чем проблема?

На питоне:

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 40]
for i in enumerate(a):
    print(i)
```

Ответ:

```
(0, 10)
(1, 20)
(2, 30)
(3, 40)
```

---

На PHP:

```
$a = [10, 20, 30, 40];

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ', ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Ответ:

```
0, 10
1, 20
2, 30
3, 40
```

---

Если у массива есть ключи, то всегда можно просто сделать счетчик:

```
$a = [1 => 10, 'hello' => 20, 10 => 30, 15 => 40];
$count = 0;

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo $count++ . ', ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Результат будет такой-же.

---

[P.S. Читать про foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php)